# Async callback functions

Tags: node.js

I have a block of code that I am working on that reads a CSV file using the fs module method createReadStream(), and on encountering a new line of data does an action with this data and then sends it off to the database in another method. One of the actions it does is hash the password in each line of code. For this I am using the bcrypt hash method, but as this method is synchronous normally it doesn't finish before the data is sent to the database, which isn't what I want.

My code block is (very) roughly structured as follows:

```
fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath)
    .on('error', error => console.log("Error"))
    .on('data', data => {
        bcrypt.hash(data.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) console.log("Error");
            else data.password = hash;
        });
        dataToUpload.push(data);
    })
    .on('end', () => uploadToDatabase(dataToUpload))
```

This ends up resulting in the password staying in the exact same form without any hashing (as bcrypt.hash does not finish before the rest of the code block). Therefore I decided to try another form as (roughly) follows:

```
fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath)
    .on('error', error => console.log("Error"))
    .on('data', data => {
        bcrypt.hash(data.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) console.log("Error");
            else {
                data.password = hash;
                dataToUpload.push(data);
            }
        });
    })
    .on('end', () => uploadToDatabase(dataToUpload))
```

This makes sure that the data isn't pushed to the array dataToUpload till the hashing is complete, however the readStream continues reading before the data can be pushed to the array, meaning nothing gets uploaded.

I have tried various implementations of async/await as two examples below show:

```
fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath)
    .on('error', error => console.log("Error"))
    .on('data', async (data) => {
        await bcrypt.hash(data.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) console.log("Error");
            else {
                data.password = hash;
                dataToUpload.push(data);
            }
        });
    })
    .on('end', () => uploadToDatabase(dataToUpload))
```

&&

```
fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath)
    .on('error', error => console.log("Error"))
    .on('data', data => {
        await bcrypt.hash(data.password, 10);
        dataToUpload.push(data);
    })
    .on('end', () => uploadToDatabase(dataToUpload))
```

However in both these cases the readStream continues reading on still. I found a possible method of pausing and resuming the reading as such:

```
let readCSV = fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath)
readCSV.on('error', error => console.log("Error"))
readCSV.on('data', data => {
    readCSV.pause()
    bcrypt.hash(data.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) console.log("Error");
        else {
            data.password = hash;
            dataToUpload.push(data);
            readCSV.resume();
        }
    });
})
readCSV.on('end', () => uploadToDatabase(dataToUpload))
```

However the data comes out as some sort of byte array instead of the data I expect?

I am wondering if anyone knows of a method to achieving this without adding too much extra overhead to the code in terms of new libraries etc. Thank you.

Comment: some thoughts that might be useful: is the ```data``` variable reused by refernce on each loop? meaning that you might need to copy the data in some way before pushing into your array. Also there is ```bcrypt.hashSync```.  Would it be an option to first read all the data from the CSV into some array, and then loop over that array so that you dont have to deal with the pause/resume of the stream.

Comment: Yeah the `data` variable is reused upon each new line of the file that is read, which is only a worry now because the next line is being read before the first line finishes processing.The `bcrypt.hashSync` has the same troubles. I certainly hadn't considered your suggestion; I will go about that now.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Promises and make every `bcrypt.hash` a Promise task that you push to the `promises` array. Then, on the `end` event, you could just wait for all the promises to resolve and proceed with uploading to the database. That way, you don't need to iterate twice over the data.

Look at the example below:

```
const promises = [];
fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath)
    .on('error', error => console.log("Error"))
    .on('data', data => {
        const task = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          bcrypt.hash(data.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
              if (err) reject("Error");
              else {
                  data.password = hash;
                  resolve(data);
              }
          });
        });
        promises.push(task);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      Promise.all(promises)
        .then((hashedDataArray) => {
          uploadToDatabase(hashedDataArray)
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
```